# How to test List<String> for empty or nullness?

Tags: java

It seems no matter what I do I get the wrong result.

My list is defined as follows:

```
private List<String> selectedPriorities;
```

Nothing odd or fancy on the getter/setter:

```
public void setSelectedPriorities(List<String> selectedPriorities) {
    this.selectedPriorities = selectedPriorities;
}

public List<String> getSelectedPriorities() {
    return selectedPriorities;
}
```

In a session bean I want to alter a different List based on the contents (or lack thereof) of this list.

Here is that code:

```
List<String> restrictList = new ArrayList<String>();
restrictList.add("lower(logs.clazz) like lower(concat(#{logs.clazz},'%'))");
restrictList.add("lower(logs.rule) like lower(concat(#{logs.rule},'%'))");
PrioritySelectorBean selectorBean = (PrioritySelectorBean) Component.getInstance("prioritySelectorBean",true);
System.out.println("constructRestrictionList selectorBean "+selectorBean.getSelectedPriorities());

if (selectorBean.getSelectedPriorities() == null) {
    System.out.println("IS NULL");
    return restrictList;
}

if (selectorBean.getSelectedPriorities().isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("IS EMPTY");
}

if (selectorBean.getSelectedPriorities().size()<1){
    System.out.println("HAS NOTHING IN IT");
    return restrictList;
}
System.out.println("NOT NULL");
restrictList.add("lower(logs.priority) in (#{prioritySelectorBean.selectedPriorities})");
```

It always falls through to NOT NULL and adds the string to restrictList.  It's making me crazy! How do I detect nothingness in this list? Here is the log snippet

```
14:24:10,057 INFO  [STDOUT] constructRestrictionList selectorBean []
14:24:10,057 INFO  [STDOUT] NOT NULL
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but instead of using ==, use equals(), i think threre's one method by that name. If i'm wrong please delete this comment

Comment: seems you really have a nonempty list here :) what doeas size() return? does .get(0) return something?

Comment: @Chuck Birkin : val == null is perfectly allright here. better dont call methods on an object if it is null ;)

Comment: I tried to print size() but got NullPointerException.  Don't ask why I didn't get that when testing for size()<1 ?  And yet it MUST be a non-empty list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the result that you're seeing if the list contains a single zero-length string:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("");

System.out.println("blah = " + list);  // displays "blah = []"
if (list.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Empty"); // doesn't get displayed
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. This seems the most likely.

Comment: I agree, but then wouldn't size() return something?  I get NPE when I try and print size().   See comment above.

Comment: @april: Without seeing some compilable code that reproduces the problem, I have no idea!

Comment: @april26: It doesn't make any sense that the code you posted doesn't throw a NPE but trying to print `size()` does. That should be impossible (assuming you're putting the print call in the same code). There's clearly something going on that we aren't seeing here, so I don't think we can help you. Try to post a small, self-contained complete example that we can run maybe.

Comment: I have now confirmed there is 1 thing in the list.  I did 3 tests on the size of the List, size()==0, size()==1, size()>1. For some reason when I try to *print* .size() I get NPE. However, when I test for .size()==1 I get a TRUE.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If I get really curious about the NPE issue I will post it separately.  Other than that I will chalk it up to user error. Maybe I typoed something.  I'm tired of looking at this already. :-P

Comment: Why doesen't `System.out.println("Empty");` get displayed? @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: @Filip - Because the list isn't empty.

Answer (score -3):

probably because

```
if (selectorBean.getSelectedPriorities().isEmpty()){
       System.out.println("IS EMPTY");   
}
```

needs a return?

Comment: I also think about it, but the log will show the "IS EMPTY" line

Comment: Not sure -- why does `System.out.println("IS EMPTY")` not get printed and why doesn't selectorBean.getSelectedPriorities().size()<1 evaluate to false?